# passing **settings info to unittest from nose

Tags: python, pyramid

I'm running my unit tests using nose.

I have .ini files such as production.ini, development.ini, local.ini.  Finally, I have a test.ini file which looks like:

```
[app:main]
use = config:local.ini

# Add additional test specific configuration options as necessary.
sqlalchemy.url = sqlite:///%(here)s/tests.db
```

In my test class I want to setup the database as I would in my app server code.  Something like:

```
engine = engine_from_config(settings)
initialize_sql(engine)

dbfixture = SQLAlchemyFixture(
    env=model,
    engine=engine,
    style=NamedDataStyle()
)
```

How does nose pass 'settings' to my test code?

I've been reading the following link for some guidance, but I haven't been able to connect all the dots.  http://farmdev.com/projects/fixture/using-fixture-with-pylons.html

Thanks much!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will need to parse the settings from the INI file yourself. Pylons used to do this automatically for you by just hard-coding a load for "test.ini". The two options you have are 1) just load the INI settings via `settings = paste.deploy.appconfig('test.ini')` or 2) loading the actual WSGI app yourself, like if you wanted to use it via WebTest `app = pyramid.paster.get_app('test.ini')` which would parse the INI file and return an actual WSGI app. Unfortunately that route doesn't give you access to the INI file directly, it automatically just passes the settings to your app's startup function `main(global_conf, **settings)`.

You may also find the [Pyramid docs](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/1.2/narr/testing.html#creating-functional-tests) on functional tests useful.

Comment: Thanks, that's just the info I was looking for.  I think depending on what level I'm testing at I'll what to create fixtures that use both approaches for setup.