# pass test config (test.ini) through nosetests to pyramid

Tags: python, pyramid, nosetests

I have seen this, which suggests parsing the config information directly:

[passing **settings info to unittest from nose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7864285/passing-settings-info-to-unittest-from-nose)

...but that still requires me to hard-code 'test.ini'.  How can I pass the name of the config file through nosetests to my application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pylons did this in the past by registering a special nose plugin that added the `--with-pylons=test.ini` option to nose. I might recommend just setting an environment variable with the filename and dealing with it that way.

```bsh
export TEST_INI="test.ini"
env/bin/nosetests
```

```
import os

ini_file = os.environ['TEST_INI']
```